# How to convert .acsm to PDF on a Mac?

Tags: pdf, ebook, epub

I just bought a book from Google Book store. 
I tried to export it to PDF or epub.

[image]

Google kept exporting .acsm file for me.

---

I am on a **Mac OS X**.

I tried to download Adobe Digital Edition
Import the .acsm file, and still see 0 option to export to PDF.

[image]

When I select show in finder, The PDF shows all white.

[image]

When I opened it, I can't see any contents

[image]

This is quite frustrated. ‍♂️

Can someone please show me how to export the book that I bought to PDF ?

Comment: According to [a Medium post](https://medium.com/@amyalice40/how-can-i-convert-acsm-to-pdf-88799da292ff) if you've imported a file it should already be converted and stored in */Users/username/Digital Editions* as a PDF file.

Comment: I did, I looked into that path, and the content seems to be encrypted to all white.